# piecewise weak convergence in $C[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

Let $P$ and the sequence $P_n$ be probability measures on $C[0,1]$ with the uniform metric. Fix $0<u<1$ and let $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ be the projections from $C[0,1]$ onto $C[0,u]$ and $C[u,1]$, respectively. Now suppose that $P_n\circ\Pi_1^{-1}$ and $P_n\circ\Pi_2^{-1}$ both converge weakly to $P\circ\Pi_1^{-1}$ and $P\circ\Pi_2^{-1}$. What additional requirement needs to be imposed to ensure that $P_n$ converges weakly to $P$? This and the obvious generalization to finitely many pieces seems like it should be a standard result but I couldn't find it in Billingsley.

Comment: Exactly what do you _mean_ by the notation $P_n\circ\Pi_j^{-1}$?

Comment: $P_n\circ\Pi_j^{-1}$ is the pushforward of $P_n$ to $C[0,u]$ for $j=1$ or to $C[u,1]$ for $j=2$.

Comment: More specifically, for $A$ a Borel set in $C[0,u]$, $P_n\circ\Pi_1^{-1}(A)=P_n(\{f\in C[0,1]:\Pi_1(f)\in A\})$. Likewise for $P_n\circ\Pi_2^{-1}$ and Borel sets in $C[u,1]$.

Comment: ???... Oh. I misread, thought that $P_n$ and $P$ were measures on $[0,1]$. They're actually measures on $C([0,1])$? Fine. Except now I'm confused by everything else. Measures on what sigma-algebra? And what sort of weak convergence are you talking about?

Comment: Ok, Borel. But what sort of weak convergence?

Comment: The measures are on the Borel sigma algebra generated by open sets. I'm considering weak convergence of probability measures, i.e. $P_n$ converges to $P$ weakly if $\int f\hspace{1mm} dP_n$ converges to $\int f\hspace{1mm} dP$ for all bounded continuous $f:C[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: OK, fine. Where I come from it would have been "continuous and vanishing at infinity", which makes little sense here since $C[0,1]$ is not locally compact. Bounded and continuous, right. Now I know what the question means anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't true as stated.  The problem is that separate weak convergence  doesn't keep track of correlations between what's going on the two halves of the interval.

Indeed, if we just consider the case of a constant sequence where $P_n = Q$ for every $n$, the question becomes:

> If $P \circ \Pi_1^{-1} = Q \circ \Pi_1^{-1}$ and $P \circ \Pi_2^{-1} = Q \circ \Pi_2^{-1}$, does $P=Q$?

And in general the answer is no.  Here's a simple counterexample.

Take $u = \frac{1}{2}$ and consider the following four paths $\omega_i \in C([0,1])$:
$$\begin{align*}
\omega_1(t) &= t - \frac{1}{2} \\
\omega_2(t) &= \frac{1}{2}-t \\
\omega_3(t) &= \left|t - \frac{1}{2}\right| \\
\omega_4(t) &=  -\left|t - \frac{1}{2}\right|.
\end{align*}$$
(I recommend sketching these paths.)  Note that
$$\begin{align*}\omega_1|_{[0, \frac{1}{2}]} &= \omega_4|_{[0, \frac{1}{2}]} \\
\omega_2|_{[0, \frac{1}{2}]} &= \omega_3|_{[0, \frac{1}{2}]} \\
\omega_1|_{[ \frac{1}{2},1]} &= \omega_3|_{[ \frac{1}{2},1]} \\
\omega_2|_{[ \frac{1}{2},1]} &= \omega_4|_{[ \frac{1}{2},1]}.
\end{align*}$$
Now let $P$ be the measure that places probability $1/2$ each on $\omega_1, \omega_2$, and $Q$ be the measure that places probability $1/2$ each on $\omega_3, \omega_4$.  Then you can easily see that $P \circ \Pi_1^{-1} = Q \circ \Pi_1^{-1}$ and $P \circ \Pi_2^{-1} = Q \circ \Pi_2^{-1}$ but $P \ne Q$.

Answer (score 1):

A first observation is that the sequence $(P_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is tight in $C[0,1]$. Indeed, for a fixed $\varepsilon$, there exists a compact set $A_1$ of $C[0,u]$ such that for each $n$, $P_n\circ \pi_1^{-1}(A_1)\gt 1-\varepsilon$. Similarly, we can find a compact set $A_2$ such that for each $n$, $P_n\circ \pi_2^{-1}(A_2)\gt 1-\varepsilon$. The set 
$$A:=\{x\in C[0,1], \pi_1(f)\in A_1\mbox{ and } \pi_2(f)\in A_2  \} $$
is a compact subset of $[0,1]$ since it is both bounded and equi-continuous. Since $P_n(A)\geqslant 1-2\varepsilon$,  the sequence $(P_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is tight in $C[0,1]$.

This sequence will converge to $P$ if the finite-dimensional distributions converge to that of $P$. But it is not clear that if $0\leqslant v\lt u\lt w\leqslant 1$, then $\mathbb P_n\{x\in C[0,1] , (x(v),x(w))\in B\}\to 
\mathbb P\{x\in C[0,1] , (x(v),x(w))\in B\}$ for each $B$ in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb R^2$ such that $\mathbb P\{x\in C[0,1] , (x(v),x(w))\in\partial B\}=0$.